# How to set a column number as an order number even we sort query by name

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sqlite, plsql

In my sql query i need to get names in asc order

**`SELECT ROWID, NAME FROM CONTACTINFO order by NAME asc`**

```
row_id  Name

 5. Arnold,
 2. Ashok
 1. Benz
 3. Cowboy
 6. Danger person
 10. Eleph
 9. Fog
 4. Gun
 8. Hello
 7. Ink
```

then automatically row-id set in jumbeled order, as shown above

but i need to add another row wich is having in ciorect order numbers like as follows

```
row_id  Name     Temp_ID            

     5. Arnold,   1
     2. Ashok     2
     1. Benz      3
     3. Cowboy    4
     6. Danger    5
     10. Eleph    6
     9. Fog       7
     4. Gun       8
     8. Hello     9
     7. Ink       10
```

i need some another row as  sequence

*I want to retrieve Some limited num of data from my large data using this Temp id like*

**`SELECT ROWID, NAME FROM CONTACTINFO where Temp_ID >3 && Temp_ID <6`**  order by NAME asc

Comment: I believe you are looking for `rownum`

Comment: Do you need the answer in Oracle's dialect or in SQLite's dialect?

Answer (score 2):

try using `row_number()`

```
select rowId, name, temp_id
from (
   select rowId, name, row_number() over (order by name) temp_id
   from contactinfo 
) A
where temp_id >3 and temp_id <6

--Results 
rowId, name, temp_id
3      Cowboy    4
6      Danger    5
```

Comment: +1.. This method could even use the stopkey optimization if you happened to have a normal b-tree index on Name.  However, I would also include "order by temp_id" to guarantee the results always come back ordered the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick ::

```
SELECT rownum,ROWID, NAME FROM CONTACTINFO order by NAME asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
SELECT ROWID ,
      TAB.NAME 
  FROM ( SELECT NAME 
          FROM CONTACTINFO 
       order by NAME asc 
       ) AS TAB 
  WHERE    ROWID>3 
       AND ROWID<6;
```

or you can also use ROWNUM..

Comment: Rowid is a unique address in each table and not a psuedo column so this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a nested SELECT: the first orders the data and adds a ROWNUM column, the second extracts the records you want.

```
  SELECT ROWID, NAME
    FROM (SELECT ROWID, NAME, ROWNUM rn
            FROM CONTACTINFO
        ORDER BY NAME)
   WHERE rn > 3 AND rn < 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct rownum will be availible after select complete so your can use it only like this:

```
select * from (select rownum as temp_id, row_id, name from contactinfo order by name asc) where temp_id >3 && temp_id <6 order by name asc
```